# How to handle multiple config

Tags: go

Is there a good way to reuse the code to read different configurations?

btw: I used config lib is `configor`

the code maybe like,

```
type Config1 struct {
    //some config items
}
type Config2 struct {
    //some config items
}

func LoadConfig1() Config1 {
    var c Config1
    configor.Load(&c, "MY/CONFIG1/PATH")
    return c
}

func LoadConfig1() Config2 {
    var c Config2
    configor.Load(&c, "MY/CONFIG2/PATH")
    return c
}
```

1. Can I reuse LoadConfig with Config1/Config2?
2. Can I design an object like `singleton` to create Config1/Config2 just once.

Comment: Don't enforce singletons, for the same reasons that you should avoid global; it makes testing needlessly complicated. You can use [sync.Once](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once) to turn anything into a singleton at the call site. Loading a config only once is even described in the docs for sync.Once.

Comment: @RelaxZeroC you could also do something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/PSdC9p-JX-l

Comment: Thansk @Peter , mkopriva ! This is very helpful to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sync` package to make sure config is only loaded once.

Example:

```
import "sync"

var (
    c Config1
    once sync.Once
    loadFunc = func() {
        configor.Load(&c, "MY/CONFIG1/PATH")
    }
)

func LoadConfig() Config1 {
    once.Do(loadFunc)
    return c
}
```

Any subsequent calls to `LoadConfig` will be ignored. For example:

```
func main() {
    c1 := LoadConfig() // Loaded, returns the value
    c2 := LoadConfig() // Not loaded, returns the first loaded value
    c3 := LoadConfig() // Not loaded, returns the first loaded value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above code will not work. It will throw an error saying

> LoadConfig redeclared in this block

Because

> Go does not allow to create function with same name. We can create
>   method with same name having different receivers.

Create receiver for config1 and config2 with same method name.

```
type Config1 struct {
    //some config items
}
type Config2 struct {
    //some config items
}

func (config1 *Config1) LoadConfig() {
    configor.Load(config1, "MY/CONFIG1/PATH")
}

func (config2 *Config2) LoadConfig() {
    configor.Load(config2, "MY/CONFIG2/PATH")
}
```

For creating an object each time you can create a function to check if instance already exists like that.

```
type Config1 struct {
}

var instance *Config1

func GetInstance() *Config1 {
    if instance == nil {
        instance = &Config1{}   // <--- NOT THREAD SAFE
    }
    return instance
}
```

Comment: thanks your comment  , then , how can I just load each config once ?
if I return Config1/2 object , I don't want to create a new object every time